# Reattaching body parts

Tags: zoology

Is there any living organism that has the ability to remove and reattach body parts at will?

I'm not talking about regeneration (like in starfish). Say I'm chasing prey, and I decide that my tail will be a hindrance. So I leave it behind, and reattach it after the hunt.

Comment: I've never heard of reattachment... that would be a very exotic trait :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this would be possible from the simple idea that all cells need energy, and if there's no nutrient flow, then how would the cells inside the detached body part stay "alive".  Doctors can currently reattach body parts right now if it's within a certain amount of time, but no animal yet can just reattach at will.